# tabular-diagonal separating line

Tags: tables

I want to add a diagonal separating line in a title box of a tabular, but the line doesn't appear (I draw it in red on the picture)

```
\begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{|l|*{2}{c|}}
      \hline
      \backslashbox{Mounth}{Year}&2015&2016 \\
      \hline
      Mai&2560&3610 \\
      \hline
      June&1465&2985 \\
      \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

[image]

Comment: Please do not post such fragments only, provide a compilable complete document

Comment: of corse, sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `\diagbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{diagbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{|l|*{2}{c|}}
      \hline
      \diagbox{Mounth}{Year} & 2015 & 2016 \\
      \hline
      Mai&2560&3610 \\
      \hline
      June&1465&2985 \\
      \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

which gives

[image]

Hope this helps!